# Нужна ли запятая после слова "физика"?

Tags: пунктуация

Этот феноменальный прогресс хорошо описывает фраза знаменитого физика, Стивена Хокинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая **не** нужна: здесь конкретный человек сначала представлен по профессии (физик, причём заменитый - принадлежность к узкому кругу людей, но ещё не указание на конкретного человека), затем по фамилии. Но если бы он был назван "самым знаменитым физиком", то названная вслед за этим фамилия стала бы вторым указанием конкретно на того же человека и потребовалось бы поясняющее уточнение, что при первом указании автор имел в виду человека с этой фамилией. Тогда понадобилась бы запятая.

Comment: Согласен, хотя обоснование (с "самый" нужна, без него - нет) непонятно. Может и при обычном физике быть уточнением, если персоналия не так важна для изложения, как профессия. Но тут-то важен именно конкретный автор, поэтому имя не уточнение, а суть указания, запятой не нужно. Я так понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Запятая точно ставится** в следующем предложении (поясняет слово с неопределенным значением):  **Этот феноменальный прогресс хорошо описывает фраза ОДНОГО знаменитого физика, Стивена Хокинга.**

Но и в приведенном варианте ее можно поставить: **Этот феноменальный прогресс хорошо описывает фраза знаменитого физика, Стивена Хокинга.**

Почему? Дело в том, что знаменитых физиков не так много, единицы наверное. И оценка эта **условная**: просто известный или уже знаменитый? В качестве простого представления (приложение без запятой) не очень подходит.

2) Без запятой лучше выглядит такое предложение: **Этот феноменальный прогресс хорошо описывает фраза известного  физика Стивена Хокинга.** Известный физик ― указание на профессию и популярность, подходящая форма для представления.